# VBA　エクセルシートでの計算結果を蓄積して、シート上に戻すプログラムの方法

Tags: vba, excel

質問事項は、モンテカルロ法のエクセルでの計算とVBAの組み合わせです。
売上高に乱数を入れて変化をさせ、その変化した5期分の売上高を元に成長率を計算するエクセルシートを作成しました。
その結果の成長率を1000回試行した結果を以って、モンテカルロ法でボラティリティを出すことをしたいです。

その1000回試行を、エクセルシートの計算を使いながら（エクセル上で経費の差引等がされています）、VBAで計算結果だけをプールして、シートに戻すプログラム式を作りたいのですが、いくつかのプログラムを参考に書いてもエラーで回りません。

現状は以下のプログラムです。修正点、使用すべき関数等をご教示頂ければ幸いです。
※1000回試行は時間がかかるので仮で数字は小さくしています。
※calculateを回して、F28の数字を抜き出して保存、プールした計算結果をシートのどこかに1000個分吐き出したいです。

```
Sub Montecarlo()
ReDim Frequency(0 To 1000) As Integer

For Index = 1 To 10
    Application.Calculate
    Return1 = Worksheets("3.ﾎﾞﾗﾃｨﾘﾃｨ推定").Range("F28").Value
    Frequency(Int(Return1 / 0.01)) = _
    Frequency(Int(Return1 / 0.01)) + 1
Next Index

For Index = 1 To 10
    Range("simuloutput").Cells(Index + 35, 1) = _
    Frequency(Index) / N
Next Index

End Sub
```

Comment: 「いくつかのプログラムを参考に書いてもエラーで回りません。」とのことですが、コードのどの箇所でどんなエラーメッセージが出たのかを質問に追記してください。また、OSとExcelのバージョンも追記いただくと良いかと思います。

Comment: 「Worksheets("3.ﾎﾞﾗﾃｨﾘﾃｨ推定").Range("F28").Value」の値は何でしょうか？回答者が再現できる情報が必要かと思います。